# `mogrify` throws "SystemError: bad argument to internal function" on passing `__slots__` based instance

Tags: python, psycopg2

I defined the below slots based class to satisfy my "mutable namedtuple with default None values" requirement:

```py
class Row:
    __slots__ = tuple(fields)

    def __init__(self):
        for attr in self.__slots__:
            setattr(self, attr, None)
    
    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        setattr(name, value)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return getattr(self, self.__slots__[i])
```

But when I use its instance for generating query string using `cur.mogrify` I get

> SystemError: ../Objects/tupleobject.c:85: bad argument to internal function

Complete code:

```py
import psycopg2 as pg2

def define_row(fields):
    class Row:
        pass # as mentioned above
    return Row


fields = ("age", "gender")
row = define_row(fields)()
row.age = 33
row.gender = "m"

rows = [row]

cur = pg2.connect(dbname="playground", user="postgres").cursor()
placeholders = "({})".format(",".join(["%s"] * len(fields)))
args_str = ",".join(
    cur.mogrify(placeholders, r).decode("utf-8") for r in rows
)  # Exception on this line
qry = f"INSERT INTO playground({','.join(fields)}) VALUES "
cur.execute(qry + args_str)
```

[`mogrify`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=mogrify#cursor.mogrify) docs do not explicitly mention what the datatype of `parameters` should be.

Comment: What's the purpose of `Row` ? As `psycopg2/mogrify` is just doing string concentration isn't `fields` enough ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer As I mentioned in the first line, I need a "mutable namedtuple with default None values". In my actual code `Row` instances are populated at different places before they are inserted into the database. Since the table columns are constant I don't want any of the functions to inadvertently add a new field but still be able to update any of the existing fields. Also, in the actual code I am creating different types of `Row` by changing `fields`, each set of fields correspond to a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Row` class needs to implement a `__len__` method:

```py
class Row:
    ...
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__slots__)
```

`cursor.mogrify` expects its second argument to be a sequence or mapping, and Python sequences are [expected](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) to define `__len__`.

Comment: I don't know C well enough to say why the absence of `__len__` crashes your code, though I'm suspicious of [this line](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/1d3a89a0bba621dc1cc9b32db6d241bd2da85ad1/psycopg/cursor_type.c#L271).  But for me at least, defining `__len__` fixes the error.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. May I know where is it mentioned that "the second argument is expected to be a sequence or mapping"?

Comment: In the documentation for [cursor.execute](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) but`mogrify` must accept the same.